# Adding leaflet plugins after map initialization?

Tags: jquery, ajax, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I'm creating a web mapping application using Leaflet.js.
Initial map creation is not a problem, but I'm trying to add features after map creation without success!

For example:

1. load HTML page
2. load Leaflet.js and CSS via AJAX requests => OK!
3. create default Leaflet map, including a custom rectangle => OK!
4. load Leaflet.Draw plug-in (including several JS files) => OK!
5. try to activate editing on rectangle => KO! No error is displayed, but the rectangle can't be edited!!

After plug-ins loading, my code is as simple as:

```
var group = new L.FeatureGroup();
rectangle = L.rectangle([p1, p2]);
rectangle.editing.enable();
group.addLayer(rectangle);
map.addLayer(group);
map.fitBounds(rectangle.getBounds());
```

Any idea?

Best regards,

Thierry

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution : just had to activate edition only after shape is added to map!

```
group.addLayer(rectangle);
map.addLayer(group);
map.fitBounds(rectangle.getBounds());
rectangle.editing.enable();
```

Best regards,

Thierry